# Checking elements in array if empty in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an array of input fields which will contain some information. I should check them if one of them are empty.

**jQuery Code:**

```
   $("#NewUserBtn").click(function () {

            var zorunluAlan = ["#YeniAd", "#YeniSoyad", "#YeniEposta", "#YeniEpostaOnay", "#YeniSifre", "#YeniSifreOnay"];

            for (i = 0; i < zorunluAlan.length; i++) {
                if (//What should i write here?) {
                    alert("Please fill all input fields!");
                    break;
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: are you considering an input filled with only space(s) as empty?

Comment: yes, spaces won't be allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use,

```
$("#NewUserBtn").click(function () {

            var zorunluAlan = ["#YeniAd", "#YeniSoyad", "#YeniEposta", "#YeniEpostaOnay", "#YeniSifre", "#YeniSifreOnay"];

            for (i = 0; i < zorunluAlan.length; i++) {
                if ($(zorunluAlan[i]).val().trim().length == 0) {
                    alert("Please fill all input fields!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using jQuery, you need to put `!$(zorunluAlan[i]).val()` as your condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a cleaner way using jQuery `filter` function:

```
var zorunluAlan = ["#YeniAd", "#YeniSoyad", "#YeniEposta", "#YeniEpostaOnay", "#YeniSifre", "#YeniSifreOnay"];

var $empty = $(zorunluAlan.join(",")).filter(function() {
    return ($(this).val().length === 0);
});

if($empty.length > 0) {
   alert("Please fill all input fields!");
}
```

Comment: `filter` is a loop :p

Comment: Eh, not really. Because in your code there's no way to stop the loop when an empty input is found, that's a loss of efficiency.

Comment: @Kolink yap, cleaner... not faster. But I bet in the end he will not break the loop so he can show a error message for each input ;)

Comment: Well, it's people like you that are the reason why the internet is so slow. But on the other hand I guess I should be thanking you because you all make my site seem infinitely faster by comparison.

Comment: @Kolink a little bit harsh, are you? ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff Maybe. But honestly, there was once a time where 4kb was a massive amount of memory to have.

Comment: @letiagoalves My point is, I like to optimise my code as much as is reasonable. For instance, not running a loop to completing if I already know the outcome.

Comment: @Kolink i'm used to people with those kind of "points". Because of <1ms of performance loss you can say with certainty that "it's people like me that are the reason why the internet is so slow". I'm glad strangers know me so well.

Comment: @letiagoalves Premature optimization is not the same as implementing optimized code the first time. If you are aware that a specific approach is more performant, then you should code that approach from the beginning, and not chalk it up to "premature optimization". Prematurely optimizing is when you write code, then go back and try to optimize it before benchmarking it.

Comment: @crush I never said my answer is more optimized than the others. I was always aware of the unnecessary iterations but I just wanted to show a different approach to the problem instead of copying from another answer like some did.

Comment: @letiagoalves Nothing wrong with that. It just seems that the comments devolved into a dialog of optimization vs. premature-optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy, even in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)

```
document.getElementById('NewUserBtn').onclick = function() {
    var zorunluAlan = ["YeniAd","YeniSoyad","........"],
        l = zorunluAlan.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( !document.getElementById(zorunluAlan[i]).value) {
            alert("Please fill all input fields! ["+zorunluAlan[i]+" is empty]");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then again, it's even easier in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="YeniAd" REQUIRED />
```

The attribute doesn't have to be in uppercase, I just made it so to make it more obivous ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#NewUserBtn").click(function () {

       var zorunluAlan = ["#YeniAd", "#YeniSoyad", "#YeniEposta", "#YeniEpostaOnay", "#YeniSifre", "#YeniSifreOnay"];

       for (i = 0; i < zorunluAlan.length; i++) {
           if (!$.trim($(zorunluAlan[i]).val()).length) {
           alert("Please fill all input fields!");
           break;
           }
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method using each

```
var zorunluAlan = $("#YeniAd, #YeniSoyad, #YeniEposta, #YeniEpostaOnay, #YeniSifre, #YeniSifreOnay"),
        invalid = false;
    if(zorunluAlan.length) {
      zorunluAlan.each(function() {
        var thisValue = $(this).val();
        if(thisValue == "" || !thisValue){
          invalid = true;
        }    
      });
    }
    if(invalid){
      alert("Please fill all input fields!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea using jQuery to add an error class

```
$("#a,#b,#c")
    .removeClass("error")
    .filter( 
        function(){
            return !this.value.length;
        }
    )
   .addClass("error");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m3WA8/

It could be simplified by using a class/attribute instead of the string of ids.